# Generalizing traversal of expressions with changes on specific nodes

Tags: haskell

I'm reading the lectures from the CIS194 course (version fall 2014) and I
wanted to have some comments on my solution to the Exercise 7 of the
Homework 5.

Here is the question:

> Exercise 7 (Optional) The distribute and squashMulId functions are
>   quite similar, in that they traverse over the whole expression to make
>   changes to specific nodes. Generalize this notion, so that the two
>   functions can concentrate on just the bit that they need to transform.

(You can see the whole homework here: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/fall14/hw/05-type-classes.pdf)

Here is my `squashMulId` function from Exercise 6:

```
squashMulId :: (Eq a, Ring a) => RingExpr a -> RingExpr a
squashMulId AddId = AddId
squashMulId MulId = MulId
squashMulId (Lit n) = Lit n
squashMulId (AddInv x) = AddInv (squashMulId x)
squashMulId (Add x y) = Add (squashMulId x) (squashMulId y)
squashMulId (Mul x (Lit y))
    | y == mulId = squashMulId x
squashMulId (Mul (Lit x) y)
    | x == mulId = squashMulId y
squashMulId (Mul x y) = Mul (squashMulId x) (squashMulId y)
```

And here is my solution to Exercise 7:

```
distribute :: RingExpr a -> RingExpr a
distribute = transform distribute'
    where distribute' (Mul x (Add y z)) = Just $ Add (Mul x y) (Mul x z)
          distribute' (Mul (Add x y) z) = Just $ Add (Mul x z) (Mul y z)
          distribute' _ = Nothing

squashMulId :: (Eq a, Ring a) => RingExpr a -> RingExpr a
squashMulId = transform simplifyMul
    where simplifyMul (Mul x (Lit y))
              | y == mulId = Just $ squashMulId x
          simplifyMul (Mul (Lit x) y)
              | x == mulId = Just $ squashMulId y
          simplifyMul _ = Nothing

transform :: (RingExpr a -> Maybe (RingExpr a)) -> RingExpr a -> RingExpr a
transform f e
    | Just expr <- f e = expr
transform _ AddId = AddId
transform _ MulId = MulId
transform _ e@(Lit n) = e
transform f (AddInv x) = AddInv (transform f x)
transform f (Add x y) = Add (transform f x) (transform f y)
transform f (Mul x y) = Mul (transform f x) (transform f y)
```

Is there a better way of doing such generalization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `transform` function is a very good start at handling general transformations of ASTs. I'm going to show you something closely related that's a little bit more general.

The [uniplate library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate) defines the following class for describing simple abstract syntax trees. An instance of the class needs only provide a definition for `uniplate` which should perform a step of transformation, possibly with side-effects, to the immediate decedents of the node.

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Identity

class Uniplate a where
    uniplate :: Applicative m => a -> (a -> m a) -> m a

    descend :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
    descend f x = runIdentity $ descendM (pure . f) x

    descendM :: Applicative m => (a -> m a) -> a -> m a
    descendM = flip uniplate
```

A postorder transformation of the entire expression is defined for any type with a `Uniplate` instance.

```
transform :: Uniplate a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
transform f = f . descend (transform f)
```

My guess for the definitions of `RingExpr` and `Ring` (the link to the homework exercise is broken) are

```
data RingExpr a
    = AddId
    | MulId
    | Lit a
    | AddInv (RingExpr a)
    | Add (RingExpr a) (RingExpr a)
    | Mul (RingExpr a) (RingExpr a)
  deriving Show

class Ring a where
    addId  :: a
    mulId  :: a
    addInv :: a -> a
    add    :: a -> a -> a
    mul    :: a -> a -> a
```

We can define `uniplate` for any `RingExpr a`. For the three expressions that have subexpressions, `AddInv`, `Add`, and `Mul`, we perform the transformation `p` on each subexpression, then put the expression back together again in the `Applicative` using  `<$>` (an infix version of `fmap`), and `<*>`. For the remaining expressions that have no sub expressions, we just package them back up in the `Applicative` using `pure`.

```
instance Uniplate (RingExpr a) where
    uniplate e p = case e of
        AddInv x   -> AddInv <$> p x
        Add    x y -> Add    <$> p x <*> p y
        Mul    x y -> Mul    <$> p x <*> p y
        _          -> pure e
```

The `transform` function we get from the `Uniplate` instance for `RingExpr a` is exactly the same as yours, except the `Maybe` return type wasn't necessary. A function that didn't want to change an expression could have simply returned the expression unchanged.

Here's my swing at writing `squashMulId`. I've split replacing the literals out into a separate function to make things look cleaner.

```
replaceIds :: (Eq a, Ring a) => RingExpr a -> RingExpr a
replaceIds (Lit n) | n == addId = AddId
replaceIds (Lit n) | n == mulId = MulId
replaceIds e                    = e

simplifyMul :: RingExpr a -> RingExpr a
simplifyMul (Mul x     MulId) = x
simplifyMul (Mul MulId x    ) = x
simplifyMul e                 = e

squashMulId :: (Eq a, Ring a) => RingExpr a -> RingExpr a
squashMulId = transform (simplifyMul . replaceIds)
```

This works for a simple example

```
> squashMulId . Mul (Lit True) . Add (Lit False) $ Lit True
Add AddId MulId
```